# SignalR and load balancing

Tags: load-balancing, signalr

We have an application that works well with any load balancing scheduling, be in random choice, random DNS or round robin. Now we'r considering using SignalR in our project, and we'r wondering how well SignalR handles these kind of load balancing schemes.

Having not tested anything yet, we'r thinking if SignalR probably works well with in this scenario if the transport uses EventSource or WebSockets, but what if it falls back on long-polling?

Im having a hard time googling more detailed information regarding this topic.

Comment: What is your load balancing policy. If you are sticking the client to a specific server I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: any of the above (random choice, random DNS or round robin). more specifically, we should handle whatever the customer likes best. ;)

Comment: Then see Hightechrider's answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of options today. [Redis](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR.Redis) or azure. I am currently using the redis bus implemention with good results.

Comment: where/how are you hosting red?